# ¿Cómo colocar video de fondo a un div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quería saber como realizar esto ya que mis intentos resultan en esto

```css
.fondoHeadHome { height: 400px;}
.fondoHeadHome>h1 { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 35px; font-weight: bold; color: white; text-shadow: 0 0 1em black;  padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 140px;}
.fondoHeadHome>p  { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 25px; color:white; text-shadow: 0 0 1em black; padding-top: 10px; }
.fondoHeadHome    { /*background-image: url("banner-1920x400-1.jpg");*/ background-position: center;  background-size: 1920px 400px;}


video { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: inherit;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 
   transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <div class="fondoHeadHome row text-center">

        <video preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop volume="0" poster="pic.jpg"  class="fillWidth">
    <source src="https://morning-shelf-6185.herokuapp.com/assets/2015-01-01-bokeh-6e0d97b003dff1c88b95db3126cd4788.mp4"> 
   </video>
   
   <h1>COMPRA Y VENDE, MÁS FACIL</h1>
   <p>
    Únete al marketplace de moda y crea tu propia tienda.<br>
    ¡Una comunidad de miles de fashionistas te espera!
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Solo puedo ponerlo en "toda la pantalla" pero quiero que tenga una altura de 400px de alto y 100% de largo (del tamaño del contenedor)

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si no se puede ver el código del fiddle no se puede saber como lo hacen, pero yo pensaría que si es el fondo entonces cambia el tamaño del div, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes incluir un ancho del 100% a la etiqueta Video y encerrar todo en un div también con ancho 100%, el alto que quieras, y overflow hidden

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
}
.video-container 
{
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth visible-lg">
        <source src="https://morning-shelf-6185.herokuapp.com/assets/2015-01-01-bokeh-6e0d97b003dff1c88b95db3126cd4788.mp4" type="video/mp4; "/>        
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: esto es justo lo que buscaba! pero lo raro es que cuando intentaba esto siempre el video desaparecia(el overflow: hidden), de todas maneras muchas gracias!

Comment: alguna idea para poder agregarle el texto que muestra mi jfiddle?, intente con z-index pero nada

Comment: Pone dentro de un DIV el contenido de tu H1 y P. a este div le asignas una clase con "position:absolute",  y top: 150px

Comment: excelente aporte, es justo lo que buscaba